# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error when ajax request make navigation for entities on webapi

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have problem about using WebApi, let me tell you about my situation in small scenario; I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution, consisting of 2 projects. One of them is a WebApi project and the other is a MVC web application. In WebApi side i have 2 class with referential integrity via foreign key. When i make ajax request from web application, I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. But when i cancel navigation property(i mean delete referential integrity) and fill object list inside class manually in WebApi controller it works without error. Probably I'm miss something but really couldn't find. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Here is my classes;

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private DateTime _EklenenTarih = DateTime.Now;
    [Required]
    public DateTime EklenenTarih { get { return _EklenenTarih; } set { _EklenenTarih = value; } }

    private DateTime _GuncellenenTarih = DateTime.Now;
    [Required]
    public DateTime GuncellenenTarih { get { return _GuncellenenTarih; } set { _GuncellenenTarih = value; } }
}

public class CariTanim : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Ad { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SoyAd { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CariHaraket> Haraketler { get; set; }
}

public class CariHaraket: BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public int CariId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Tutar { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Tarih { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CariId")]
    public virtual CariTanim cari { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my controller;

```
public class CariController : ApiController
{
    private CariContex db = new CariContex();

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public object GetAllCari()
    {
        List<CariTanim> carilist = db.cariler.ToList(); 

        return carilist;
    }
}
```

also my contex is here;

```
public class CariContex: DbContext
{
    public CariContex()
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnSTR"].ConnectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<CariTanim> cariler { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CariHaraket> hareketKayitlari { get; set; }
}
```

also my webapiconfig is here;

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and finaly i make ajax request like this;

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _url + "Cari/GetAllCari",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        success: function (CariList) {
            if (CariList.length > 0)
            {
                if (CariList[0].ResponseCode == 1) {
                    $("#CariList").empty();
                    $.each(CariList, function (index, cari) {
                        console.log(cari);
                        $("#CariList").append("<li>" + cari.Ad + " - " + cari.SoyAd + "</li>");
                    });         
                }
                else {
                    alert(CariList[0].ResponseMessage);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (request) {
            console.log(request);
            var msg = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            alert("Failed:\n\n" + request.status + " - " + request.statusText + "\n\n" + msg["Message"]);
        }
    })
```

Comment: You are calling the service from a different domain (page and service aren't on the same domain), for this you must activate CORS: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: can you show .config file ?

Comment: thanks for your reply i will share my web.config file below

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the step that tells jQuery it is making a CORS request. Change your ajax request to:

```
$.ajax({
        url: _url + "Cari/GetAllCari",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        success: function (CariList) {
            if (CariList.length > 0)
            {
                if (CariList[0].ResponseCode == 1) {
                    $("#CariList").empty();
                    $.each(CariList, function (index, cari) {
                        console.log(cari);
                        $("#CariList").append("<li>" + cari.Ad + " - " + cari.SoyAd + "</li>");
                    });         
                }
                else {
                    alert(CariList[0].ResponseMessage);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (request) {
            console.log(request);
            var msg = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            alert("Failed:\n\n" + request.status + " - " + request.statusText + "\n\n" + msg["Message"]);
        }
    })
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks for your reply, when i add  xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, this line, my error message changed. Now i get; 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.20:58673/api/Cari/GetAllCari?_=1472616095514. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:58893' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Change the origin to list the sites. When called from both your API and web project for dev, the origin would be "http://localhost:58893,http://localhost:apiport#". Using a wildcard for the origin, especially with security is an unsafe practice.

Answer (score 0):

my webapi web.config file is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnSTR" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;integrated security=SSPI;&#xD;&#xA;         attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|Cari.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

and also my web applicaction web.config file is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```